# HardHat testing swapTokensForEth reverted with reason string 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'

Tags: solidity, hardhat, erc20, uniswap

I have this function in my contract for testing:

```
function swapTokensForEth(uint tokenAmount) public {
    require(tokenAmount > 0, "Need to send some tokens");
    require(tradingOpen, "Trading is not open yet");

    // The user should have enough tokens and approval before calling the swap function
    require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= tokenAmount, "Not enough tokens");
    require(allowance(msg.sender, address(uniswapV2Router)) >= tokenAmount, "Not enough allowance");

    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = address(this);
    path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();

    // Transfer tokens from the user to Uniswap
    uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        tokenAmount,
        0, // accept any amount of ETH
        path,
        msg.sender, // ETH goes to the user who initiated the swap
        block.timestamp + 300 // deadline
    );
    }
```

Here is the hardhat test:

```
it("Swap TOKENS > ETH", async function() {
    await owner.sendTransaction({ to: coin.address, value: ethers.utils.parseEther("100") });
    
    // open trading
    await coin.connect(owner).openTrading();
    await ethers.provider.getBalance(coin.address);
    await coin.balanceOf(owner.address);

    // swap eth for tokens
    await coin.connect(owner).swapEthForTokens({ value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1") });

    // approve tokens (not sure if I should approve uniswap or contract)
    
    const tokenBalance = await coin.balanceOf(owner.address);
    await coin.connect(owner).approve("0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D", tokenBalance);
    await coin.connect(owner).approve(coin.address, tokenBalance);
    console.log("Users token balance: " + tokenBalance);

    const ownerBalanceBeforeSwap = await ethers.provider.getBalance(owner.address);

    // Using half of balance just to make sure it's less than balance
    let halfTokenBalance = tokenBalance.div(2);
    await coin.connect(owner).swapTokensForEth(halfTokenBalance);

    // Owner's balance after swap
    const ownerBalanceAfterSwap = await ethers.provider.getBalance(owner.address);

    console.log("Owner's ETH balance after swap: " + ownerBalanceAfterSwap);


    // Expect the ETH balance after swap to be more than before swap
    expect(ownerBalanceAfterSwap).to.be.above(ownerBalanceBeforeSwap);
});
```

Basically, everything works (I have a working swapEthForTokens function also), but when it comes to using this function, I get this error:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'
    at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d)
    at Coin2.swapTokensForEth (contracts/ERC20 copy.sol:289)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:526:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
    at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1840:23)
    at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:517:16)
    at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1532:18)
```

Has anyone had anything similar or know how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: I also tried approving tokenpair address, but that changed nothing:

Answer (score 0):

The router looks at the calling contract to get the tokens, but there aren't any (the user has them). So you can try taking the tokens from the user and approving the router like this:

```
transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenAmount);
this.approve(uniswapV2Router.address, tokenAmount);
```

So the whole function will be:

```
function swapTokensForEth(uint tokenAmount) public {
    require(tokenAmount > 0, "Need to send some tokens");
    require(tradingOpen, "Trading is not open yet");

    // The user should have enough tokens and approval before calling the swap function
// ! This is not needed
//    require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= tokenAmount, "Not enough tokens");
//    require(allowance(msg.sender, address(uniswapV2Router)) >= tokenAmount, "Not enough allowance");

    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = address(this);
    path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();

    // Take from user and Approve Router for swap
    transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenAmount);
    this.approve(uniswapV2Router.address, tokenAmount);

    // Transfer tokens from the user to Uniswap
    uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        tokenAmount,
        0, // accept any amount of ETH
        path,
        msg.sender, // ETH goes to the user who initiated the swap
        block.timestamp + 300 // deadline
    );
}
```

Note that the user doesn't need to approve the router in this case but your contract instead.

In any case I don't see the point for someone to call this function when the can call the uniswap router directly.

Comment: Thank you. Yeh, I didn't know you needed ABI to call uniswap directly. Was getting errors whil trying to do so, but now everything works